# Spring: how to parse uploaded zip file?

Tags: java, spring, zip, zipinputstream

I uploaded my **zip** archive to the server and want to open `.txt` and `.jpg` files in it. I successfully get my archive in my Controller and get the name of each file via `ZipEntry`. Now I want to open it but for this I should get a full path to my file.

I haven't found how I can do that. Could you suggest some approach how to do that ?

**Update**

I try to use example have been suggested below but I am not be able open the file

```
ZipFile zFile = new ZipFile("trainingDefaultApp.zip");
```

I have got the `FileNotFoundException`

So I return to my start point. I have upload form in Java Spring application. In controller I had got a zip archive as `byte[]`

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(UploadItem uploadItem, BindingResult bindingResult){
    try {
        byte[] zip = uploadItem.getFileData().getBytes();
        saveFile(zip);
```

Then I had got each `ZipEntry`

```
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(zip);
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);

    ZipEntry entry = null;
    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        String entryName = entry.getName();
        if (entryName.equals("readme.txt")) {
            ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(entry.getName()); // here I had got an exception
```

According to docs I did all right but as for me it is strange to pass the file name only and suspect that you successfully will open the file

Comment: What do you mean? You said you open it successfully; what do you not have a "full path" to?

Comment: I have opened CommonsMultipartFile that contains my zip archive as byte[]. I convert it to ZipInputStream and in loop have got a ZipEntry for each file in my archive. Now I want to read this .txt file and .jpg file but ZipEntry contains only names of this files. So I haven't a full path to this files and can't open it as new File("d:/some.txt")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my uissue. The solution is work directly with ZipInputStream. Here the code:

```
    private void saveFile(byte[] zip, String name, String description) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(zip);
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);

    Application app = new Application();
    ZipEntry entry = null;
    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        String entryName = entry.getName();
        if (entryName.equals("readme.txt")) { 
           new Scanner(zis); //!!!
           //... 
           zis.closeEntry();
```

Answer (score 1):

`zipFile.getInputStream(ZipEntry entry)` will return you the inputstream for the specific entry.

Check out the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getInputStream(java.util.zip.ZipEntry)) for `ZipFile.getInputStream()` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getInputStream(java.util.zip.ZipEntry).

**Update:**

I misread your question. For using the `ZipInputStream`, there is sample code on Oracle's website (http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/) that shows you how to read from the stream. See the first code sample: Code

- Sample 1: UnZip.java.

Copying here, it is reading from the entry and writing it directly to a file, but you could replace that with whatever logic you need:

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
ZipEntry entry;
while((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
   System.out.println("Extracting: " +entry);
   int count;
   byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
   // write the files to the disk
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(entry.getName());
   dest = new 
   BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);

   while ((count = zis.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
        dest.write(data, 0, count);
   }
}
```

Comment: My bad, just saw that you have a ZipInputStream, not a ZipFile. There is sample code on Oracle's website (http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/) that shows you how to read from the stream. See the first code sample: Code Sample 1: UnZip.java.

Comment: Mmm..how can I use ZipFile? In consructor I should pass the File that I can't create without a full path to this file. In case when I pass the name of file as String I got FileNotFoundException

Comment: I try this example. I have same excaeption. It says that file not found. For test I hardcoded the name of my archive "tetx.zip" but I have failed when try to create new FileInputStream("tetx.zip"). Is it wrong or the issue in another place?

Comment: If you are able, you may want to post your code. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Paul. I expend my question with code and my description. Probably it helps to unsderstand the cause of issue.

Comment: link to sample code is broken. Possibly this is the one that was referenced, nice read! http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html