# How to run validation on an uploaded file before uploading it all in java?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat, file-upload

I'm using Spring-mvc and and tomcat 7 - and I need to compose a controller for file uploading.
When the server gets the uploaded file, it needs to run some validation tests before persisting it in the database.
The validation is done using some meta-data which is part of the file (ZIP file).
Thing is, I would like to fail fast... and run the validators on the meta-data before uploading all the file (as it might be very big).

For doing that, I have two options:

1) Expose a validation-url for the client - which can be used when the client tries to upload big files - this is very easy to implement, but doesn't 'feel right' for me.

2) Try to fetch the meta-data before uploading all the file (someone offered to get a stream to the file, and fetch only the meta-data part of it - but I failed to do that...) - Is that possible?

Is there a way to implement the second option?

Thanks

Comment: Is the file uploaded via a browser? If so, can't you use JavaScript for it?

Comment: You can't. You'd have to do it client-side. (And you still need to validate server-side.)

Comment: @Ivar - Yes - it is done via browser - but I wanted to do it in server side

Comment: @chrylis - Thanks.